# How to pass values from pygame sprite group

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm building a simulation that generates a bunch of soldier sprites. They run across a map, towards some guns.  I want the guns to shoot the soldiers. I'm trying to pass the soldier class rect x and y values to the tower objects.

Here's the relevant code :

```
class soldier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  
    def __init__(self):  
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  
        self.rect.centerx = soldier_starting_positionx               
        self.rect.centery = soldier_starting_positiony    

    def x(self):
        return (self.rect.centerx)  

class gaurdtower(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.rect.centerx = tower_starting_positionx
        self.rect.centery = tower_starting_positiony

    def update(self):
        print (soldier.x)
```

Both these classes generate multiple instances from within a for loop and are added to an all_sprite pygame group.

The print output is a list of lines like this :
function soldier.x at 0x00000286C296F0D0

What I want is a simple integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soldier.x references a function in the soldier *class*. Classes do not contain any of the actual soldier data. You need to reference an object of the soldier class.

For example:

```
soldier = soldier()
soldier.x() # should return the soldiers x value.
```

I'd look at a tutorial before attempting something like this: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll build up some familiarity with object oriented programming and then have another go.